# Understanding Type in Compiled Scala File

Tags: scala, javap

Given:

```
$cat build.sbt
scalaVersion := "2.12.1"

$cat src/main/scala/net/X.scala
package net 

trait Foo 
object X {

    val a: Int with Foo = 42.asInstanceOf[Int with Foo]

    println(a + a)

}
```

After compiling it via `sbt compile`, I [javap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html)'d the output `class` files:

```
$javap target/scala-2.12/classes/net/X\$.class 
Compiled from "X.scala"
public final class net.X$ {
  public static net.X$ MODULE$;
  public static {};
  public int a();
}

$javap target/scala-2.12/classes/net/X.class 
Compiled from "X.scala"
public final class net.X {
  public static int a();
}
```

Why does `a` have the type, `int`?

I had specified a type of `Int with Foo` in `object X`.

Comment: This is just a guess, but it looks like an optimization - since `Foo` is empty and the only thing used in the program is the + function, there's no need for any other type. I wonder what would happen if you tried to pass a to a function that only accepts `Foo`s.

Answer (score 2):

This is simply the way all intersection types in Scala are compiled to JVM bytecode. The JVM has no way to represent things like `Int with Foo`, so the compiler erases the type to the first "simple" type: `Int` in this case. This means that if you use the value `a` like a `Foo` the compiler has to insert a cast into the bytecode.

Take a look at the following REPL session:

```
Welcome to Scala 2.12.1 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_111).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> trait Foo { def foo = "foo" }
defined trait Foo

scala> trait Bar { def bar = "bar" }
defined trait Bar

scala> class FooBar extends Foo with Bar
defined class FooBar

scala> class Test { val foobar: Foo with Bar = new FooBar }
defined class Test

scala> object Main {
     |   def main(): Unit = {
     |     val test = new Test().foobar
     |     println(test.foo)
     |     println(test.bar)
     |   }
     | }
defined object Main

scala> :javap -p -filter Test
Compiled from "<console>"
public class Test {
  private final Foo foobar;
  public Foo foobar();
  public Test();
}

scala> :javap -c -p -filter Main
Compiled from "<console>"
  ...
  public void main();
    Code:
      ...
      15: invokeinterface #62,  1           // InterfaceMethod Foo.foo:()Ljava/lang/String;
      ...
      27: checkcast     #23                 // class Bar
      30: invokeinterface #69,  1           // InterfaceMethod Bar.bar:()Ljava/lang/String;
      ...
```

`Int with Foo` is actually a special case. `Int` is a final type and `Foo` is a trait. Apparently the compiler prefers final types and classes over traits. So in `Foo with Bar` where `Foo` is a trait and `Bar` is a class, the type still gets erased to `Bar` instead of `Foo`.